# passing an argument as list using argparse but facing issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to pass a list of values as arguments using this code:

```
parser.add_argument('--items', nargs='+', help='items to buy')
```

and using this to pass the items:

```
--items=bread milk
```

from debugging I see that it is making a list of one index and that has 'bread milk' into to
while I was hoping it would make a list of two items like ['bread','milk'].
how can I fix it?

I saw some a lot of people mentioning this code to make it happen:

```
parser.add_argument('-l', '--l', nargs='+', help='list = [title, HTML]')
```

but when I use the same line of code, just changing "l" to "items", it doesnt work.

Comment: How exactly are you parsing the arguments? `python3 tmp.py --items=bread milk` would only recognize `bread` as an argument for `--items` and throw an error for the unrecognized `milk` argument.

Comment: If you drop the `=`, you'll get a list like you are expecting.

Comment: @chepner I get this error: error: unrecognized arguments: --items bread milk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--items", nargs='+', help="items to buy")
args = ap.parse_args()
items = args.items

print(items)
```

Test:

```
python3 test.py -i bread milk eggs butter
```

Output:

```
['bread', 'milk', 'eggs', 'butter']
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @chepner, however, if the OP has multiple arguments to be passed, wouldn't we be required to pass the argument label? That is the primary reason why I always use 'items = str(args['items'])'. It just makes things more flexible IMO!

Comment: i really cant figure out what am i doing wrong. its not working for me, returns a list of one index with ['bread milk']

Comment: @qabootar Can you share your command line, that is, how you are passing the arguments to your code?

Comment: im basically using the debug of python, using the launch.json file. I have a bunch of arguments set up like this: 
"args": [
                "--check", "--allow", "-i bread milk"
            ]

Comment: Have you tried this without debugger?

Comment: @qabootar try `"args": ["--check", "--allow", "-i", "bread", "milk"]`. There's no way for it to know that you intend `"-i bread milk"` to be three separate tokens.

Comment: @MichaelRuth this worked! but how though. I don't understand, Shouldn't it be passed like arguments are passed in the terminal? or does launch.json file takes it differently? Thanks tho! it worked

Comment: Yes, this is how arguments are passed in the terminal, `-i bread milk` are three arguments and `argparse` uses their positions along with the `-i` flag to associate them with items. Try passing `-i "bread milk"` to your script via the terminal and you'll see they're interpreted as two arguments, `-i` and `bread milk`. When you pass `"-i bread milk"` as an argument via launch.json, it's interpreted as a single item: `" bread milk"`. It looks like `argparse` sees it as `-i" bread milk"`.

Comment: @ShivikaP The value of the `items` destination is going to be the same whether you access it as an attribute or if you create a `dict` first. Converting it to a string is doubly pointless, because you erase the distinction between one item and another unless you basically parse the string back to a list.